# fullcalendar events drag and drop not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, drag-and-drop, fullcalendar

The drag and drop works fine on other browsers just firefox that has an issue.

I have read enough to know that Firefox has a different mechanism for drag and drop but nothing I found has helped
Tried implementing `jsEvent.preventDefault();` as the commentor suggest [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19055244/530933)
but that did not change the behavior and Im not sure how to implement the marked as answer portion which does `event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', 'anything');`

Here is my drag and drop code:

setup draggable tr

```
$('#workOrdersTable tbody tr').each(function() {
    var tds = $(this).children('td');
    if (tds.length > 0) {
        var workOrder = $.grep(workOrders, function(e) {
            return e.woNumber == tds[0].innerText;
        })[0];
        if (typeof workOrder !== "undefined" || workOrder !== null) { // store the Event Object in the DOM element so we can get to it later
            $(this).data('workOrder', workOrder);
            // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
            $(this).draggable({
                zIndex: 999,
                revert: true, // will cause the event to go back to its
                revertDuration: 0 //  original position after the drag
            });
        }

    }
});
```

How can I get this working in Firefox?

FullCalendar setup implementing drop

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    editable: false,
    droppable: true,

    //edit existing
    eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
        populateEvent(calEvent, true);
    },

    //create new
    drop: function(date, jsEvent, ui ) {
        //alert('jsEvent '+jsEvent);
        jsEvent.preventDefault();

        var workOrder = $(this).data('workOrder');
        workOrder.title = workOrder.woNumber + ' ' + workOrder.account
        workOrder.description = workOrder.problemDescription;
        workOrder.start = date;
        workOrder.end = moment(date).add(1, 'hour'); //change default so the start and end dont match
        populateEvent(workOrder, false);
    },
```

Comment: I also use Firefox and don't have problems with Drag&Drop. I'm just shooting in the dark, but do you also have issues with this d&d?: http://jsfiddle.net/VjNFn/16/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with setting the data onto the draggable row

```
var workOrder = $.grep(workOrders, function(e) {
        return e.woNumber == tds[0].innerText;
    })[0];
```

needed to be

```
        var woNumberTemp = tds[0].textContent || tds[0].innerText;
        var workOrder = $.grep(workOrders, function(e) {
            return e.woNumber == woNumberTemp;
        })[0];
```

Appearently for chrome `tds[0].innerText` is fine but firefox needs `tds[0].textContent`